# How to make sure condition variable signals successfully

Tags: c++, concurrency

I'm learning C++ concurrency, and there's conditional variable as the built-in synchronization primitive.

My question is:
For two threads which ensures synchronization via cv.wait() and cv.signal(). If one of them is de-scheduled by the Operating System, so it's in the ready state rather than in the blocked state, so the signal emitted by another thread will be ignored. Thus the whole program will reach a dead state.

For this particular situation, how to ensure the cv.signal() does wake up another successfully?

Comment: If a thread isn't running when a signal is sent, and no other thread receives the signal, then it'll be rescheduled and the CV signaled reasonably promptly by the OS.  You don't have to worry about that - it's behaviour required by the implementation.  If it's not fast enough for you in some particular usage, then don't use a condition variable (do a busy spin, burning CPU cycles - low-latency but very inefficient, and a very anti-social thing to do on a box not dedicated to your software).

Comment: Condition variables are used together with mutexes, and correct usage of condition variables and mutexes will handle this race condition properly.